# What is the implication of installing Kentico in the root of IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, content-management-system, kentico

I have a Kentico web site that I installed it on the root of my IIS website, I am not planning to have multiple sites just one however I wanted to know what is the implication of installing Kentico this way what am I forgoing and what am I getting. I am using Kentico 7 by the way.

I looked on the Kentico 7 documentation but there was no explanation of what the differences are.

You can see the online document here: [Local IIS server](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?web_installer_local_iis_server.htm)

See below an image of the web installer with the root installation check-box.

[image: Image of the web installer with the root installation checkbox]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

each site hash its own base (root) virtual directory. Every other virtual directory created under the site becomes a part of URL naming space of this site (but you can map it on whatever physical location you want). In production environment you usually want the application "to be its own site". You don't want it to behave like some sub-application or take care of web.config inheritance...

For more info I **strongly** recommend sections "Virtual Directories" and "Sites" in [this great article](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis).

Should you have any other questions regarding installation don't hesitate to contact me directly.

Petr Svihlik
Technical Leader / Group Product Manager of Tools
petr dot svihlik at kentico dot com
https://twitter.com/PetrSvihlik

Comment: I will also submit a new requirement to improve the documentation.

Comment: So there is no implications other then the IIS/.Net ones? I understand the principals of virtual sites and sites in IIS I was jus tnot sure if it had any other implication outside of IIS i.e. with Kentico. If there isn't one then that is great.

Comment: I know there was an issue on IIS 6 and earlier where WebDAV module didn't work when Kentico CMS wasn't installed to root. And I think there was also some issue with URL rewriting. But I think since Windows Vista (IIS7 and higher) there are no technical difficulties regarding Kentico. It can smoothly run either in root vdir or child vdir.